# Error: Cannot find module "@firebase/polyfill"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I am facing the below mentioned error on Mac:

```
Error: Cannot find module "@firebase/polyfill"
    at webpackMissingModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:71203:65)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:71203:160)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:71154:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:109392:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:109376:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:36504:70)
```

Working environment:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.1
npm   : 5.1.0 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This error is fixed.

> npm install @firebase/polyfill